# If $\begin{bmatrix}XY \\ X\end{bmatrix}$ has full column rank, then does $X$ have full column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider the rectangular matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, the square matrix $Y \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, and the block matrix $Z = \begin{bmatrix}XY \\ X\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{2m \times n}$. If $Z$ has full column rank, then does $X$ necessarily have full column rank as well? I haven't yet been able to think of a counterexample, so I'm interested to know whether this is true or false.

Comment: hint: Its false, I found a counterexample for $m=n=2$

Comment: @CalvinKhor could you provide the counterexample?

Comment: As a further hint towards a counterexample: The simplest nonzero singular $X$ that I know of is $X=e_1 e_1^\top$. Then $Xe_2=0$. Can you find a 2-by-2 $Y$ such that $XYe_2\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
Y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

$Z = Y$.   $Z$ has full column rank and $X$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

Not true!

Counterexample:

$X=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ which clearly has column rank $1$.

Let $Y=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$.

$XY=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

$Z=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&0\\1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ which has full column rank.

Comment: I would add at the end that "$Z$ has full *column* rank".

Comment: Just edited, thank you

Comment: A good follow-up exercise: What is the minimum condition on the matrix entries of $Y$ for this example to work?